# Why the MyRegisterClass() function is necessary in WIN32 projects?

Tags: winapi, registerclass

In the default code that Visual Studio generates when creating a Win32 project, there's a function called **MyRegisterClass** with the comment:

```
//    This function and its usage are only necessary if you want this code
//    to be compatible with Win32 systems prior to the 'RegisterClassEx'
//    function that was added to Windows 95. It is important to call this function
//    so that the application will get 'well formed' small icons associated
//    with it.

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    ...
    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}
```

But this function uses RegisterClassEx that is not exists prior Windows 95. I really don't understand the comment. What they are mean?

What the main purpose to have **MyRegisterClass** function, and why it's so necessary for compatibility with earlier versions of Windows?

Comment: MyRegisterClass is not necessary, RegisterClass(Ex) is necessary. Why do you think that RegisterClassEx not exists on Win95?

Comment: @user2120666 he said PRIOR to Windows 95

Comment: OK. My mistake,

Comment: The comment says it only necessary if you want this code to be compatible with Win32 systems prior to the 'RegisterClassEx'. I don't understand WHY and HOW?

Comment: I suspect the template project has been updated piecemeal over the years but no one's ever noticed the comment is out of date. Presumably originally it used `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: It was EXtended from the legacy RegisterClass to support WNDCLASSEX, allowing you to specify the small icon at the upper-left of the window caption.  It is quite irrelevant today, nobody creates programs for Windows 3.x anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant  AND? Why they are used MyRegisterClass in their templates for the years? The comment is completely garbage... and usage of this functions is completely dullness...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MyRegisterClass` function is a ***helper*** function. It *encapsulates* the call to the API function `RegisterClass[Ex]`, since there's a lot of messy parameter setup that needs to be done in order to make the call. The complete function definition looks like this:

```
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
  WNDCLASSEX wcex;

  wcex.cbSize         = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
  wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
  wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
  wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
  wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
  wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYAPP));
  wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
  wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MYAPP);
  wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
  wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

  return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}
```

Extracting this out into a helper function—as opposed to inlining it—keeps your code clean and more readable. As far as performance goes, the compiler will inline it automatically, if that's appropriate.

Another reason why it makes sense for this to be a helper function is historical, and that is what's described in the comments:

> ```
> //    This function and its usage are only necessary if you want this code
> //    to be compatible with Win32 systems prior to the 'RegisterClassEx'
> //    function that was added to Windows 95. It is important to call this function
> //    so that the application will get 'well formed' small icons associated
> //    with it.
> ```

You see, the `Ex` suffix on an API denotes "EXtended". The `RegisterClassEx` function was introduced with 32-bit Windows (API v4.0, Windows 95). Back in 16-bit Windows, there was only `RegisterClass`. 32-bit Windows supported both variants, for backwards-compatibility, but the "extension" that `RegisterClassEx` added was the ability to set a small icon. If you want to have nice small icons (instead of ugly ones, generated by a low-quality stretching algorithm from the large icon), you need to call `RegisterClassEx`. But if you want to target 16-bit Windows, you can't call `RegisterClassEx`; you need to stick with `RegisterClass`. So, if you encapsulate the call to `RegisterClass[Ex]` in a helper function, you can easily modify the code, changing which API function it calls and therefore which version(s) of Windows your app can target.

The comment is trying to convey this information, but doing a relatively poor job of expressing itself.

You can completely ignore this today. Nobody targets 16-bit Windows anymore. Always call `RegisterClassEx`, and forget that `RegisterClass` even exists. That doesn't eliminate the advantage of encapsulating this code in a function for readability.

Note, further, that the default Win32 project template bundled with Visual Studio separates the small and large icons in separate ICO files and thus assigns them separate resource IDs. This was presumably done for the same historical reasons, so you could compile for 16-bit Windows without having the small icon getting in the way, but again is completely unnecessary today. You can combine both icons into a single ICO file, and load them selectively:

```
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
  WNDCLASSEX wcex;

  wcex.cbSize         = sizeof(wcex);
  wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
  wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
  wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
  wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
  wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
  wcex.hIcon          = (HICON)LoadImage(hInstance,
                                         MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYAPP),
                                         IMAGE_ICON,
                                         GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON),
                                         GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON),
                                         LR_DEFAULTCOLOR | LR_SHARED);
  wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
  wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MYAPP);
  wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
  wcex.hIconSm        = (HICON)LoadImage(hInstance,
                                         MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYAPP),
                                         IMAGE_ICON,
                                         GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON),
                                         GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON),
                                         LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);

  return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}
```